# not getting data with fql query

Tags: javascript

I tried this code to get data from facebook but I am getting just user's name and fb ID. I need the some basic data of my friends i.e. AGE, GENDER, LANGUAGE my query is working in developers facebook but not in java code.
plz help.
Thanks in advance.

```
<script>


        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
            }
        }
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId : '1654526974811057',
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml : true, // parse social plugins on this page
                version : 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });

        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api( '/me', function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                document.getElementById('userDetails').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + ' below are your information!' + '<br><b>Name:</b>' + response.name +'<br><b>Gender:</b>' + response.gender + '<br><b>Email:</b>' + response.email + '<br><b>Facebook link:</b>' + response.link + '<br><b>Local:</b>'  + response.location  + '<br><b>Facebook Id:</b>' + response.id;
                           var store = [];
                            var oldf = console.log;
                               console.log = function(){
                                store.push(arguments);
                                oldf.apply(console, arguments);
                                }

    });
}
    </script>
    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" nonlogin="checkLoginState();" ></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask a question. You need much more details than that

Comment: Try to understand that nobody here can see your screen or knows what you're working on or has anything to do with whatever you're describing.  Try to imagine that *other people are not you*.  Then try to *describe* what you're doing, the problem you're facing, and the steps you've taken.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is offtopic, not unclear what he is asking

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask for more permission in your scope with FB, like public profil and email, there is many more option.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
}, { scope: 'public_profile,email' });
```